# Requests certificate error in jupyter notebook / jupyter lab - python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ssl-certificate, ipython, jupyter-lab

When running:

```
import requests
requests.get("https://github.com")
```

I get the following error:

```
Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

If however i run the same command in iPython the command runs with no error.

I also checked the path to the certificate for both the notebook and iPython with:

```
requests.certs.where()
```

And the path is the same for both.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Could it be that you have different versions of Python when invoking IPython and when starting Jupyter?

Comment: I checked an i use the same exact python version (and executable).